# Desktop application pop-up handling with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I am automating a web application using selenium webdriver and java in which after hitting login button a desktop application is launched and the control is no more associated with the webdriver. When the application is launched, the whole desktop screen goes into background and the dialog box comes in front. I need to access that dialog box to enter pin.

I have tried using robot class, AutoIT and AUT but not able to access that dialog to enter pin.

Sorry... i dont have enough reputation to load image.
please help.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting modal window:-

You can navigate to it and send pin using `driver.switchTo().alert().sendkeys("<pin>");`